# preg_match_all reading from file returns empty array

Tags: php, file, preg-replace, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

I'm trying to read a file and filter its content. The result I'm expecting is this: https://regex101.com/r/uMTrtd/3 but I don't know why I'm not getting it. I've tried changing the PCRE limits with no result and I don't know what else to do.

If I run the `preg` with the actual string instead of reading the file it works, but the `var_dump($file)` returns a string.

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
var_dump($file);
$text = preg_replace('/(cve: .+? Pág\. [0-9]{1,2} )/u','', $file);

$re = '/(La señora|El señor) (.+?):(.+?\. (?=(La señora|El señor) (.+?):|Eran las .+?\.))/u';
preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);

?>
```

You can check the content of the file here https://regex101.com/r/uMTrtd/3

Comment: The code works, you should look at how the file is saved and encoded.

Comment: And how can I see that? The file is encoded in UTF-8

Comment: Did you download the file? I thought you copy/pasted and save the file yourself.

Comment: I generated the file through PHP

Comment: Well that's my tip for you, can't really help you with that. The code runs fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(cve: .+? Pág\. [0-9]{1,2} )/us','', $file);


$re = '/(La señora|El señor) (.+?):(.+?\. (?=(La señora|El señor) (.+?):|Eran las .+?\.))/us';
```

"s" makes it search also over newlines